# Error going to next form on clicking datagride tuple

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio

My code-

```
public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(id);
            f2.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox4.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();



        }

        public void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(id);
            f2.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            f2.textBox4.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }
```

my gui-

[image]

My problem is that when I click on the datagrid tuple it is not going to the next form.
It is just freezing.
edit-
this how I am filling the datagrid -

```
CheckBox[] Locations = { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3 };
                CheckBox[] Profiles = { checkBox4, checkBox5, checkBox6 };

                string locs = string.Join(" or ", Locations.Where(c => c.Checked).Select(x => $"location = '{x.Text}'"));
                string profs = string.Join(" or ", Profiles.Where(c => c.Checked).Select(x => $"profile = '{x.Text}'"));
                MessageBox.Show(locs);
                string query = $"select * from jobs where ({locs}) and profile in(select profile from jobs where ({profs}))";


                OracleCommand comm2 = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
                OracleDataAdapter MyAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();//adapter acts as interface btw database and dataset(which is collectio of tables)
                MyAdapter.SelectCommand = comm2;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();//datatable represents a single table in database 
                MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
```

this might help in debugging.So my query basically returns a row of tuples and I will click any of the rows and it should go to another form where the column values of that row are stored in the textbox of the second form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer look at [`CellContentClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?view=netframework-4.7.2) event, you'll see that this event:

> Occurs when the content within a cell is clicked.

I just tried your posted code, and it works. It's a bit tricky though using `CellContentClick` event because you cursor has to click on the content of the cell exactly. I advise you to use [`CellClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=netframework-4.7.2) event instead.

This event:

> Occurs when any part of a cell is clicked.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(id);
    f2.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    f2.textBox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    f2.textBox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    f2.textBox4.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

**Update**:

Since you're telling me that by adding this code, it also didn't work. You need to make sure that your `DataGridView` has been subscribed to those events:

1. Open you form in design view.
2. Click on your DataGridView
3. Press F4.
4. Now check the events. They should contain the name of the function you added. Like this:

[image: events]

If you prefer to do this programatically, you can add this code in the `Form.Load` event:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += dataGridView1_CellClick;
```

Comment: I tried your code but its still not opening a new form...I tried clicking everywhere...should I post something more?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob, I have tried the 3 events we talked about. They are all working. I will update my answer with something that you "might" have missed.

Comment: Thank you so much..its always the little things!

Comment: We've all been there. Just make sure to always debug your code. If you actually debugged it, you would have noticed that the event wasn't being triggered I suppose. Good luck with your project furthermore.